# Can unregisterForContextMenu completely unregister a View?

Tags: android, contextmenu

I have a ListView, which can either have a context menu, or not. I am using `registerForContextMenu` and `unregisterForContextMenu` respectively and have no problems with the registration itself or anything related to the context menu showing up/working.

When a view is registered for a context menu, when the user clicks it, its background changes gradually from orange through yellow and then to white. This does not happen when a view has never been registered for a context menu (it stays the same color). However, when I use `unregisterForContextMenu` to unregister the view in question, this effect is still active and may confuse the user - he/she will expect a context menu because of the effect. This shows that `unregisterForContextMenu` does not completely reverse the effect of `registerForContextMenu`.

**My question is**: Is there a way to *completely* unregister a View from getting a context menu?

If someone has a clearer idea of how `(un)registerForContextMenu` works internally, please share your thoughts.

**Edit:** I just saw that this does not apply to HTC's sense interface, as there the 'whitening' effect is not implemented. So the question applies only to the default Android interface.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you registering, then unregistering, a context menu? If your activity is not using a context menu, don't register it.

Comment: Suppose there are categories, subcategories (more than one level) and articles. All articles support a context menu and all categories (and subcategories) do not. My client wants me to show this in a uniform way. So I show categories and when a category is clicked I only change the contents of the ListView. And this is the moment when I want to unsubscribe for the context menu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turned out to be very simple. `registerForContextMenu (View v)` is simply calling `v.setOnCreateContextMenuListener (this)`, referring to the calling Activity as the `OnCreateContextMenuListener`. The problem is that in the View class, the `setOnCreateContextMenuListener` is checking if the view is long-clickable, and if it isn't, it sets it to be. However, the method `unregisterForContextMenu (View v)` only calls `v.setOnCreateContextMenuListener (null)`. But the `setOnCreateContextMenuListener` doesn't check whether the passed `OnCreateContextMenuListener` is null or not, thereby always leaving the view in question long-clickable.

The solution was to just call `v.setLongClickable (false)` manually.